# Actuarial and Financial mathematics book suggestion

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, finance, actuarial-science

Recently, I was introduced with one of my course named "Introduction to Actuarial and Financial Mathematics". The book I followed was too dry and it's not contain a detail explanation of proof as well as examples. Due to pandemic situation, I have to study all of the course material by myself. The topics are:

- Basic concept of Mortality Table
- Construction of Mortality Table
- Annuities
- Assurances
- Net premiums

For rest of the topics I follow **schaum's outlines Mathematics of Finances** which contain a lot of examples. It will be a great help if someone suggest some good books which contain those topics with some details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great book that has all the details you need. Kind of dated but still useful for seeing how things work together and contains all of what you mention in your question:

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26810639-actuarial-mathematics

Comment: Thanks, @Samuel. Sorry for late response. Yes, this book has a lot of details. but still I couldn't find some topics like whole life **Immediate Annuity**, **Temporary Annuity** and **Increasing Annuity**. The reason I asked for a book is because my book didn't explain how they derive formulas aka definition of those term. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/Egt9rlx.jpg) is one sample. Could you redirect/suggest/provide any link/book/article where I can get the proper definition/proof of [THIS](https://i.imgur.com/UKpYFyv.png), [THIS](https://i.imgur.com/e6CGbdX.png).